# Error in magento 2.3 Class Does Not Exist in backend and frontend

Tags: error, magento2.3, frontend, backend, class

I upload my magento 2.3 on my server, so when i navigate in the frontend the navbar is disappeared see the photo
[image]
so when change the mode to developer, to see the error in backend output print this error:
Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\ Attribute\Backend\Sortby does not exist
So What's going on?.

Answer (score 0):

You have space in class name after Category - may by that is reason why class reader cannot find class.